# asp.net MVC secure root folder only for authorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

I am having this small extranet service where users can log in, get all sorts of info and download few files.

Is it possible to secure root folder in MVC asp.net project? I am having a project where users have to log in before using any material. How ever if I use for example "/material" folder for every pdf, jpg, etc. files, other unauthorized users can see those files also.

For example everybody can see this file if they type www.example.com/material/pdf-file.pdf So I want only authorized / logged users to see this file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do that, but there are a lot ways to accomplish that.

A simplified scenario could be:

- [Disable directory listing on IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- Create a custom "download wrapper" controller+action for the purpose of serving of those files.
- Then wherever you create Action links, generate them using a [`HtmlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which would redirect the client to the "wrapper" controllers action. You can pass the filename in a parameter.
- On the "wrapper" controller you could utize the [`[Authorize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute or better yet, without using such attributes everywhere you could use [FluentSecurity](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity) for handling the authorization.

After you create the "wrapper" controller your `URL` for getting a file could look like:

> www.example.com/*download*/*file*/pdf-file.pdf

This example `URL` assumes *controller* name is 'download' and *action* name is 'file'.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it work. Here is how I did it.

The first I added this line to Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

This allows dot chars in .pdf, .png, etc... in url's.

I added to RouteConfig.cs new routing for controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Material",
            url: "Material/Download/{file}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Material", action = "Download", file = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I created a new controller "Material".

```
// GET: Material
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Download(string file)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/App_Data/Material/{0}", file));

        if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            string mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

            return File(path, mime);
        }

        return HttpNotFound();
    }
```

And also transfered material folder inside app_data.

This seems to work nicely. Only authorized users can access to material folder.